# Как правильно кэшировать запросы в laravel

Tags: laravel

Есть страница с выводом всех товаров(их очень много), также на странице есть не большой фильтр по get, понадобилось это все кэшировать.

Получилось сделать таким образом:

```
$cache_name = 'builder.'.$category->id;
$gets = \Request::all();
foreach ($gets as $key => $get) {
   $cache_name .= '.'.$key.'.'.$get;
}
$prods = Cache::remember($cache_name, 10, function () use ($builder) {
  return $builder->paginate(20);
});
```

Правильно ли это сделано? И есть ли более лучшие способы кэширования запросов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема кеширования хороша, если все средства оптимизации запросов уже исчерпаны. Для начала посмотрите узкие места запросов с фильтрами, если надо - добавьте индексы.
И в последнюю очередь прибегайте к кешу.

Старайтесь не записывать в кеш коллекции моделей, т.к. это увеличивает его размер минимум в 2 раза, например:

```
// неоптимальный кеш
Cache::remember('key', now()->addHour(), function(){
    return Product::where(/* */)->get();
});

// Более предпочтительный
Cache::remember('key', now()->addHour(), function(){
    return Product::where(/* */)->get()->toArray();
});
```

Касательно вашего проекта: можно создать сервисный класс фильтра товаров, константами определить, какие фильтры товаров вообще есть (цена, параметры и т.п.). Записывать параметры в фильтр, например

```
class Filter {
    const PRICE = 'price';
    const DURATION = 'duration';
    const AGE = 'age';
    // ... other filter keys 

    private $filters = [];

    public function getFilter(string $key, $default = null)
    {
        return Arr::get($this->filters, $key, $default);
    }
    // setFilter, unsetFilter ... etc

    public function getHash()
    {
        return sha1(collect($this->filters)->sort()->toJson())
    }
}
//////////////////
$filter = new Filter();
foreach($request->query->all() as $filterName => $filterValue){
    $filter->setFilter($filterName, $filterValue)
}

///////
// какая-то логика

// добавили в модель query scopes (заготовки запросов)
// например Product

public function scopeFilterMinPrice(Builder $builder, $price){
   return $builder->where('price', '>=', $price);
}
// и другие заготовки с префиксом filter

// далее используем объект фильтра таким образом
$builder = Product::query();
foreach($filter->getFilters() as $filterName => $filterValue){
    // главное, чтобы были scopes методы для каждого фильтра
    $method = 'filter' . ucfirst(Str::camel($filterName));
    $builder->{$method}($filterValue); // вызываем query scopes
}

$builder->offset(/**/)->limit(/**/);

return Cache::remember("products:".$filter->getHash(), now()->addHour(), function()use($builder){
    return $builder->get()->toArray();
});
```

Для перевода запросов в строку я иногда пользуюсь своими хэлперами:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as eBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as qBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause as Join;

if(!function_exists('query_hash')) {
    /**
     * генерирует hash из строки запроса
     * @param Relation|Join|qBuilder|eBuilder $builder
     * @return string
     */
    function query_hash($builder)
    {
        return sha1(query_print($builder));
    }
}

if(!function_exists('query_print')) {
    /**
     * возвращает sql запрос с биндингами
     * @param Relation|Join|qBuilder|eBuilder $builder
     * @return string
     */
    function query_print($builder)
    {
        return vsprintf(str_replace(['%', '?'], ['%%', "'%s'"], $builder->toSql()),$builder->getBindings());
    }
}
```